# how the iphone/ipod touch connects to others when making a video call over wifi

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch

I've searched everywhere for this but haven't found anything.

I'm trying to understand what APIs/classes are used when making a video chat. More specifically how does the iphone/ipod touch use your contact list to connect to another one over wifi and then how does it do voice and video. Is the contact list on an apple server that it uses to connect through to?

Thanks
A.R.

Comment: The address book is on the device; there's no reason why it should be on an Apple server unless you're syncing it over MobileMe. FaceTime should just be using the address book to look up the phone number or email address of the person you want to call, in order to send *just that* to an Apple server in the same way the Phone app sends the phone number of the person you want to call to your carrier.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled and [this](http://blog.tmznet.com/2010/07/how-iphone-4-factime-video-calls-work/) came up